# Select common colums for certain rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table like this:

```
table: roomMembers
roomid    member
0         User1
0         User2
0         User3
1         User1
1         User2
1         User4
etc...
```

I need a SQL query that will return the roomid where both UserX and UserY is a member, for example, if i was to wrap it in a function it would look like:

```
findCommonRooms("User1", "User2");
```

In this particular case it should return an array of 0 and 1.

Comment: Could you provide us a sample of the output result you are expecting? I am not able to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you the roomid where both 'User1' and 'User2' is member.

```
SELECT roomid
FROM roomMembers
WHERE member in ('User1','User2')
GROUP BY roomid
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct, you could easily find the members who have actually been in same rooms before.

```
CREATE TABLE roomMembers
(
roomid int,
member varchar(10)
);


INSERT INTO roomMembers VALUES (0,'Member1')
INSERT INTO roomMembers VALUES (0,'Member2')
INSERT INTO roomMembers VALUES (0,'Member3')
INSERT INTO roomMembers VALUES (1,'Member1')
INSERT INTO roomMembers VALUES (1,'Member2')
INSERT INTO roomMembers VALUES (1,'Member4')
```

This should give you all the rooms where multiple people have stayed.

```
WITH q1
AS (
    SELECT member
        ,count(*) total_count
    FROM [dbo].[roomMembers]
    GROUP BY member
    HAVING count(*) > 1
    )
SELECT r.roomid
    ,q1.member
FROM q1
JOIN dbo.roomMembers r ON r.member = q1.member
order by r.roomid;
```

Hope this helps!